# ReSharper says this expression is always true. Why?

Tags: c#, xml, resharper

I'm trying to determine if XML node attribute exists.  Here is my code:

```
var xmlNode = element.Attributes("parent");
if (xmlNode != null) // Expression is always true
{
    var parentNodeId = element.Attribute("parent").Value;
    if (groupables.ContainsKey(parentNodeId))
    {
        parent = groupables[parentNodeId];
    }
}
```

ReSharper is telling me that the line where I check if xmlNode is null will always be true.  Why is that?  I am parsing an XML file, some of the nodes contain "parent" as an attribute.  Some do not.  So why does ReSharper think otherwise?

Comment: Sometimes resharper fails

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Not in this case ;-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because `Attributes` will return a 0-length list, which is never null

Comment: Correct, so the OP should be checking the `Count` property to detect if the attribute is present or not, or using `Attribute` (singular) and checking for null. I would do the null check on the singular form so you don't have to access the attribute twice.

Comment: look for `if (xmlNode.Any())` instead